# How to convert XLS file to CSV using Excel Interop and return it instead of saving it

Tags: .net, excel, csv, interop, xls

I'm converting the XLS file to CSV but this code is saving it. I don’t want to save it but instead return it. Is there any way to do it using Excel Interop.

```
Application app = new Excel.Application();
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(myfile);
wb.SaveAs(Path.ChangeExtension(myfile, “.csv”), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
wb.close(false);
```

Comment: Excel converts a worksheet to CSV by saving it to disk in CSV format - there's no function available which directly returns a CSV representation as a string.  If you need that then you will have to read it from disk after the SaveAs.

Comment: Is there a way to read it immediately without clicking the browse button?

Comment: It's just a text file and you already know the location, so Yes you can use code to read it.